Keyboard Stops Working After Opening The LapTop Lid in Ubuntu OS
I started using Ubuntu recently, and I'm facing an annoying problem when opening laptop's lid after closing it without shutting down or suspending the laptop. The problem is the built-in keyboard stops working completely. And I need to plug-in another keyboard to be able to log in again. The mouse pad works perfect without any problems.
My Device Details:
Lenovo Ideapad slim 3 Ryzen 7 7730 u
Radeon Graphics card
512 GB SSD
Came With Windows 11 Home
What I tried:

I Deleted the system and installed it again
I Changed The Value of /etc/default/grub RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
I disabled USB suspending
I installed another Kernel version
I disabled intel_usbt
I asked Chat_GPT and searched about the problem

I'll be pleased if someone can help me
